# Checking usage of YouTube Data API v3 by cloud monitoring API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-cloud-monitoring

Basically, there is some quota each day for using YouTube Data API v3.
Posting a video costs 1600 units.
Getting some information about a video cost 1 unit.

*I want to check how many units of quota I have used today by the means of monitoring API of the Google Cloud platform.*

However, the YouTube Data API is not covered in the documentation of [cloud monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3).

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube Data api is not part of the cloud monitoring system. It is part of the discovery services api, and there is no monitoring API for discovery APIs.

If you want to know if you are over your quota, make a call google will return a quota error to you.

Comment: I understand that makes a call will return a quota error if over-used.            But since you could __view the usage of youtube API in the dashboard__ of the control panel in GCP.  I believe there is some way to view that in monitoring API.

Comment: There is no API for the Google developer console for monitoring this.   The discovery apis are more then ten years old this was well before GCP.  I have been working with these apis since the beginning.  If there was something i would tell you.

Comment: how do you judge that the youtube api's calling data and graph shown in the dashboard are from discovery API?  The [discovery api](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using#basic_api_description)  seems only to provide some basic information about some API.  Even if that's the case, why don't we just directly call the discovery API to get the usage data?

Comment: I have research for 2 days, seems  `serviceruntime.googleapis.com` could eventually solve the problem.

Comment: Well thats great if you get it to work answer your own question.  With an example. after ten years it would be really nice if they had added something that we could use.  It would be awesome if they had merged the Google cloud quota metrics with the Google apis quotas.

Comment: @DalmTo I do believe that the doc of the google cloud platform could be more structured.  I have deep dive into many APIs to eventually discover this.           Their documentation about one service or api is great. However not so much guidance for user to find out which one fits their need.